# Adding a OpenAPISpecFilter using annotations or ResourceConfig

Tags: java, swagger, jersey-2.0, openapi

I am trying to use the OpenAPISpecFilter from Swagger-Core 2.0.5, which produce OpenAPI 3.0 spec.

The [samples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/2.0/java/java-jersey2-initializer-configfile/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/util/ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl.java) provide such a class as an example, but when running the sample application, the filter does not seem to be active. I observe the same behaviour on my application.

The documentation is not very clear on the subject :

> ### Filters
>
> You can provide an OpenAPISpecFilter implementation in
>   configuration to be able to filter out or even completely change the
>   resolved definition.
>
> When implementing the filter, extending AbstractSpecFilter is probably
>   the most convenient option, as it allows to override only the needed
>   filter method.
>
> A simple example of a filter could be:

```
/**  
* Sample filter to avoid all resources for the /user resource 
**/ public class NoPetOperationsFilter extends AbstractSpecFilter {

    public static final String PET_RESOURCE = "/pet";

    @Override
    public Optional<Operation> filterOperation(Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        if (api.getPath().startsWith(PET_RESOURCE)) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(operation);
    } } check out the tests for some additional examples of filter usage.
```

> When relying on provided JAX-RS resources to expose the API, this
>   filter will be applied automatically [...]
>
> [source](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Extensions#filters)

The class in present in my classpath and I beleive I am relying on the **provided JAX-RS resources to expose the API**.

I do not see any Swagger/OpenAPI Annotation or element in the `ResourceConfig` that would allow me to declare the Filter manually.

The documentation continues:

> [...] otherwise, e.g. when serving the definiton from own servlet or resource, you can apply it for example like:

```
OpenAPI oas = resolveDefinition()
OpenAPISpecFilter
SpecFilter f = new SpecFilter();
oas = f.filter(oas, filterImpl, getQueryParams(uriInfo.getQueryParameters()), getCookies(headers),
        getHeaders(headers));
```

This is strange, as the `OpenAPISpecFilter` object does not have a `filter` method.

I am probably just missing something here, but the situation is unclear (as the documentation). I could not find any working exemple on the sample/open-source projects, I just would like to know how this specific Swagger/OpenAPI filters must be registered.

Comment: Note that `Swagger 2.0, aka OpenAPI 3.0` is not true, `Swagger 2.0` is equivalent to [`OpenAPI 2.0`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md)

Comment: Is that so ? I must be misunderstanding something then, the documentation states

> Swagger Core 2.X produces OpenApi 3.0 definition files.
Source : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Extensions (top of the page)

The JAR file version of swagger-core is 2.0.5 (current latest)

Comment: Ah yes, this is quite confusing. I meant `Swagger 2.0` specification is equal to `OpenAPI 2.0` specification. But you're right that `Swagger Core 2.X` produces `OpenAPI 3.0` specification. I am not a fan of the naming of everything. Since you said `Swagger 2.0` I assumed you were talking about the specification.

Comment: Ok I see, I updated the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at [AbstractSpecFilter](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/26d72bf5fd2d54e5e514ddcf3861d125d2f95b42/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/core/filter/AbstractSpecFilter.java) there are methods called `filterOpenAPI`, `filterPathItem` etc.. maybe `filter` in their example was meant to reflect that. `filterOpenAPI` for example does reflect the parameters which they provided for the `filter`method.

Comment: I am not sure what OpenAPISpecFilter is supposed to do there. I think that line should have been removed. The `io.swagger.v3.core.filter.SpecFilter´ class has the filter method with the signature they recommend to use.

Comment: Looks like it needs to be configured (in web.xml). Just doing a search for `ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl`, you see the [different ways it is configured for each different kind of app](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/search?p=2&q=ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl&unscoped_q=ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl)

Comment: All of those examples assume you've declared a specific servlet to serve up the docs. I'm using `swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2` where OpenApiResource automatically serves the docs. How do I configure that with a filter?